# How to have sorted results when using Data Movement API?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I'm using marklogic 9 and data movement api to export the results of a search. I create a query like:

```
StructuredQueryDefinition query = ...
String sortOptionsXml = "<sort-order  direction=\"" + sortDirection + "\">" + "<path-index>" + sortIndex + "</path-index>" + "</sort-order>";
String queryAsXml = "<search xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search\">" + query.serialize()
                + "<options><search-option>filtered</search-option>\n" + sortOptions + "</options>" + "</search>"
RawCombinedQueryDefinition combinedQueryDefinition = queryManager
            .newRawCombinedQueryDefinition(new StringHandle().with(queryAsXml).withFormat(Format.XML));
```

and then I send this query to a QueryBatcher, created like:

```
QueryBatcher batcher = databaseClient.newDataMovementManager().newQueryBatcher(query)
```

and start the batcher as:

```
batcher.withBatchSize(500)
        .withThreadCount(8)
        .onUrisReady(
                new QueryBatchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processEvent(QueryBatch queryBatch) {
                        LOGGER.info(String.join(",", queryBatch.getItems()));
                    }
                }
        )
        .onQueryFailure(Exception::printStackTrace);
JobTicket jobTicket = dataMovementManager.startJob(batcher);
batcher.awaitCompletion();
dataMovementManager.stopJob(jobTicket);
```

However, if I look the returned items, they are not sorted by the sort options I used, not even inside a batch. Is it possible to get the URIs sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself: it is not possible. I created a ticket on marklogic github project (https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/916) and the final conclusion was (https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/916#issuecomment-385773027):

> DMSDK splits the huge tasks into small chunks by directing the query
>   to each forest and getting the URIs from each forest in batches. Even
>   if we pass in the sort options, we would get an ordering per forest
>   and not on the whole. Since we can't get a global ordering, we chose
>   to drop the options and it doesn't make sense to have an ordering at
>   the forest level.